# Spring Boot error when AspectJ 1.8 Plugin compiles

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I face an issue that seems to be resolved [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7176)
Mine is an aspect that needs AspectJ. There is a

```
> "if()"
```

condition in my aspect.

I have enabled this plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Plugin Management sections has this.

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <!--<sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/MyAspect.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The error is this.

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) @ enterprise ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] Field value processing of @ConfigurationProperty meta-data is not supported
    <unknown source file>:<no line information>
[ERROR] Internal compiler error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to   write metadata at  

  org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.writeMetaData(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:385)
```

If I add an empty `<sources/>` tag the plugin does not find any AspectJ code to compile.
If I add the entire `<sources/>` tag as shown above I get the same error again.

The only alternative I see is to go for AspectJ LTW configuration which is not needed here.
Any advice ?

Update: I am using LTW now which isn't straightforward. But still I didn't understand this problem with compilation.